# Javascript: render a list of components

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have

```
const bold = content => <b>{content}</b>;
const aside = content => <aside>{content}</b>;
```

Now, I write:

```
aside("hello world");
```

And everything performs correctly.

---

Next, suppose I want to render a list of components in aside:

```
const bold = content => <b>{content}</b>;
const aside_items = ???
```

Such that when I write:

```
aside_items([bold("hello"), bold("world")]);
```

The following HTML is produced:

```
<aside>
  <b>hello</b>
  <b>world</b>
</aside>
```

How does one implement `const aside_items = ???`?

Comment: i do not understand your question

Comment: The trick that is your array: `[bold("hello"), bold("world")]` equals to `[<b>hello</b>, <b>world</b>]` because you are calling `bold` function when creating that array. As a proposal instead of creating function, you could just define some variable with all items, like: `const aside_items = [bold("hello"), bold("world")];` and then just render it's values: `<aside>{...aside_items}</aside>` by *spreading that list*.

Comment: @YUzhva ah, ok.  tried the ... inside the function and got an error on chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are using JSX, but if not you could use `Template literals` and then just `join` array items to string.

```js
const bold = content => `<b>${content}</b>`;
const aside_items = content => `<aside>${content.join('')}</aside>`

const items = aside_items([bold("hello"), bold("world")]);
document.body.innerHTML += items;
```

Comment: ok, so with this one I have gotten the html to be output exactly correct.  However, the browser is interpreting it as a string literal. Any way around that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, `<b>` tags are html elements inside browser not strings.

Comment: Yeah, they were rendering with `"<the html>"` in chrome--so it was a quoted string. I'll accept though, because it does produce the desired html.

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate over the `items` array and return a string of HTML markup:

```
const aside_items = (items) => {
   let arr = [];
   for (let i in items) {
      arr.push(items[i]);
   }
   return '<aside>' + arr.join('') + '</aside>';
}
```